# Multiple iTunes libraries - podcasts merged after 11.1 upgrade?

Tags: itunes, macos

I use two iTunes libraries (Windows7x64, shift-key on iTunes launch) to manage content for several different devices (iPhone 4S, iPod Nano, iPad2), and have been doing this for a couple of years.

After the upgrade to iTunes 11.1 I went to sync my iPod (on library 2) and found that all the podcast subscriptions from library 1 had been added.  I double-checked that I was in the right library and then removed them.

When I went back to library 1 to sync my iPhone I found that the podcasts I had unsubscribed and deleted in library 2 were gone from library 1 as well.

So it appears it's no longer possible to have two completely separate iTunes libraries any more?

Anybody know how to force the two libraries to be completely separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the new option that controls this.

Preferences/Store/Sync Podcast Subscriptions and Settings

Or maybe this option already existed but its setting was changed as a result of the upgrade.  Disabling this restores previous behavior.

There are also threads at Apple Support, [such as this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23029619#23029619) about problems with podcasts after the 11.1 upgrade.